# How to get followers and followee list of >500 Twitter users using tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, error-handling, tweepy, social-networking

I want to create a network graph of followers and followee of a list of over 500 Twitter users and for that, I am storing followers list and followee list of every user in user_list. I tried this code but it took too long to execute (it's been >18hrs) and at the end gave an error that I pasted here: https://pastebin.com/dgBgGN6M

```py
user_list = []

for user in unique_creators:
    ff_list = []
    followers = []
    for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=user, count=1000).items():
        followers.append(follower.screen_name)
    
    friends = []
    for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name=user, count=1000).items():
        friends.append(friend.screen_name)    
        
    ff_list = [followers, friends]
    user_list.append(ff_list)
```

Here `unique_creators` is the list of screen_names of Twitter users. Can someone please tell if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Your `handle_errors` method makes no sense. 1. Instead of swallowing the error you should see why the error happens and post that error traceback. 2. your while loop does not exit. It's stuck in there.

Comment: I made the changes and added a link to the error. Please have a look.

Comment: The machine you are running your script on can you `ping api.twitter.com`?

Comment: ```PING tpop-api.twitter.com (104.244.42.66) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 104.244.42.66: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=267 ms
64 bytes from 104.244.42.66: icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=267 ms
```
I am getting this continuously as output.

Comment: You should search for `Temporary failure in name resolution`. I can't give you a straight solution since it depends on too many factors. You'll have to read through and see what applies to you. You have a DNS problem.